# Get the left and right objects when Compare-object SideIndicator is == in powershell

Tags: powershell, comparison

I'm doing a comparison with compare-object just for the property *Name*. When the SideIndicator is "==" can I have access to both objects? I want to have access to the other properties that are not "Name".

```
   Compare-Object $env1 $env2 -IncludeEqual -Property "Name" | ForEach-Object {         
            $_.LeftObject.Size
            $_.RightObject.Size

        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to get access to both objects. If you remove the Name comparing then you can get acess to the object itself via the InputObject property. That said, there's no left or right object since it is the same object (equal).

Comment: Thank you Shay! Yeah, I tried several ways but it seems that I need to go search with the name that I have. But that is so much slower that I'd really like to avoid it.

Comment: At the end I went with an hashtable and it was quite fast.